# Are these C6294 and C6201 warnings in Visual C++ 2022 legitimate?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

Visual C++ 2022 00482-90000-00000-AA381 produces these warnings:

```
Warning C6294   Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.    VisionResearch  C:\src\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp    562
Warning C6201   Index '2' is out of valid index range '0' to '1' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'this->val'.   VisionResearch  C:\src\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp    562
```

in this and other similar OpenCV 4.5.4 functions:

```
template<typename _Tp, int m, int n> inline
Matx<_Tp, m, n>::Matx(_Tp v0, _Tp v1)
{
    CV_StaticAssert(channels >= 2, "Matx should have at least 2 elements.");
    val[0] = v0; val[1] = v1;
    for(int i = 2; i < channels; i++) val[i] = _Tp(0);
}
```

Obviously, `channels` and `val` size can be greater than 2, which makes this warning incorrect. Am I missing something?

---

I dug a bit deeper, and this is an excerpt from the documentation of this warning (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6294):

```
This warning indicates that a for-loop cannot be executed because the terminating condition is true. This warning suggests that the programmer's intent is not correctly captured.
```

Note `cannot be executed`, which is obviously incorrect.

---

More digging. It seems that this old standing issue is very low on the list of priorities for Visual Studio team. This bug https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Code-analysis-false-positive-warning-C62/759216 from 2019 is still not fixed.

---

Definitions of data members in the code snippet:

```
template<typename _Tp, int m, int n> class Matx
{
public:
    enum {
           rows     = m,
           cols     = n,
           channels = rows*cols,
....
    _Tp val[m*n]; //< matrix elements
};
```

Comment: The warning seems too broad to me. It's perfectly reasonable to write a `for` loop that sometimes doesn't execute any iterations.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it would be reasonable if the compiler can determine statically that the loop would *never* be executed.  As long as it's a warning and not an error.

Comment: What is the type of `channels`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's: `enum {
           rows     = m,
           cols     = n,
           channels = rows*cols,`

Comment: You also left out the definition of `val`.  If the compiler can detect that the body of the loop causes undefined behavior, it's perfectly within its right to complain about the loop itself.  The only issue in that case would be the misleading text of the warning.

Comment: @MarkRansom I added the definitions.

Comment: You know about [`#pragma warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170), right?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes. I'm a frequent user, but almost always the warnings I suppress are justified.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the warning is related to the condition in the for loop

```
CV_StaticAssert(channels >= 2, "Matx should have at least 2 elements.");
val[0] = v0; val[1] = v1;
for(int i = 2; i < channels; i++) val[i] = _Tp(0);
```

because it will not be executed if `channels` has the acceptable value equal to `2`.

Comment: Sure, but the warning reads `initial condition does not satisfy test` instead of a more appropriate `initial condition may not satisfy test`.

Comment: @PaulJurczak This is a question to the developers.:)

Comment: I will file a bug report. See my edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the for loop is using `channels` but the size of `val` is `m*n` the compiler may have trouble determining that those are the same number.  So the second warning is about the possibility of undefined behavior.  Once the compiler has decided that undefined behavior is possible, all expectations of rational behavior have gone out the window.  That includes the generation of compiler messages.

Comment: *the compiler may have trouble determining that those are the same number*, which means it should not issue a definite statement, which is incorrect, otherwise huge amount of C++ code would be peppered with bogus warnings. Here is a code snippet paraphrasing the one I posted, and as expected, no warnings are issued: https://godbolt.org/z/dvo7KodPz

Comment: @PaulJurczak you're missing my point - once the compiler has deduced undefined behavior, it has no obligation to produce sensible output and I assume that includes warning messages.  Your job is to fix the bogus determination of undefined behavior, and I'll bet if you do that the warning goes away.

Comment: *possibility of undefined behavior* - my point is that the mere possibility of undefined behavior is not a good reason to produce these warnings, not mentioning the false statements contain therein. Otherwise, any unchecked iterator or index would produce these kinds of warning, which you will probably agree would be insane. Bogus determination should not require bending your code to fit some arbitrary weakness of the compiler.